# Change app.config at runtime - in memory - not working "Access denied"

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

```
    var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    if (configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key] == null)
    {
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(new KeyValueConfigurationElement(key, value));
    }
    else
    {
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    }
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I've read all stackoverflow related questions and the answers are: You can't write to app.config file at run time. Which is fine for me. But I also found accepted answers that said you can change the in-memory app.config with the above code.
But I get the same error that the file is read-only... even though this code is supposed to only change in-memory?

What am I missing?

I am using .net framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Have you tried making the file writable?

Comment: The file isn't set to readonly.

Answer (score 1):

@Muhkuh,
The app.config file is only when you are working on your source code and developing/programming the application.
After you build of publish the project, the build output is written to the folder that is configured in the project properties.
All the values you specified in the file, are read once the application's executable is ran and the first time any configuration is read by the `ConfigurationManager` class.
So, the configuration file should be changed before the application is ran. If you want to change the configuration values, you should consider a read/write configuration provider, and store any configurations in a table in the application's database or a configuration database (This will be determined by the design of the application components).
So, changing the configuration values that are come from the actual `app.config` file is not a best practice and is not recommended anyway.
Regards